# How to solve the inappropriate results on text expansion

Tags: python, pandas

i want to expand contraction in my dataset. I get the results but they don't match.

This is the code i've tried

```
contractions_dict = {
"a.l.": "antara lain",
"A.M.v.B.": "Algemene Maatregel van Bestuur",
"gg.": "gang",
"Jl." : "jalan ",
"T." : "teuku",}

# Expanding Contractions 
dataset = pd.DataFrame(list_kalimat, columns=['token', 'entitas bernama', 'kalimat'])
dataset.token.replace(to_replace=contractions_dict, inplace=True, value=None, regex=True)
```

I will show  a comparison between the words before expand and after. This the the result from code above

| before | after |
| --- | --- |
| Jl. apel | jalan apel |
| dianggap | diangangp |
| tengah | teukungah |

the strange thing is why the letter `t` in word `tengah` is also expanded and `gg` in word `dianggap` is also expanded.

I think it's because the fullstop in the dictionary is not read but I don't know it's true or false. what I want to ask how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Do you understand what `regex=True` does?

Comment: You probably want `regex=False`

Comment: In a regular expression, `.` matches any character.

Comment: if I make regex = False then the contraction will not be expanded @Barmar

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dataset.token.str.replace()`?